# iphone Three20 TTMessageController Address Book

Tags: iphone, three20, addressbook

I'm trying to use the TTMessageController from Three20 to send messages through a custom web service.  I'm not clear on how I can incorporate contacts from the user's address book.  I see the model mock address book in the sample app, but the sample only contains names.  Is there a way to set the datasource of TTMessageController to be the address book?

Thanks,
Howie

Answer (score 0):

You should use MFMailComposeViewController. TTMessageController was created before iOS 3, when in-app emailing functionality didn't exist in Apple's SDK. MFMailComposeViewController does pretty much anything most developers would want it to do and it automatically uses the device's contacts, so you won't have to go through the trouble of setting up the model yourself.

Using TTMessageController would be a good solution if you needed to customize the presentation of the fields or customize the delivery of the message.

iOS Documentation (Sending a Mail Message): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendingaMailMessage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010415-SW1